# VS2013 silverlight web debugging close browser(Internet explorer)

Tags: internet-explorer, silverlight, debugging, visual-studio-2013, silverlight-5.0

I install fresh instance off Visual studio professional 2013 update 3 to my computer.

When I hit the f5 in vs 2013, build solution open browser(Interner explorer) load page and close browser.

Output:

```
iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130555813163773023): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing\v4.0_12.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)
```

If I chose firefox open the page and work as should, but in firefox can't debugging.

What should be the problem for closing down internet explorer.